# Best lightning generation/simulation algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, simulation

So I need some algorithm for programing lightning path generation. Which one is fastest and at the same time realistic?

Comment: Asking 'what is the best' is a subjective and argumentative way to ask a question. You might instead ask for people to post their experience, and then you might need to check the community-wiki box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a few papers on the subject - the first one looks fairly realistic and is purported to be fast.

**[Fast Animation of Lightning Using an Adaptive Mesh](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/FAST_LIGHTNING/lightning_tvcg_2007.pdf)** presents a fast method for simulating, animating, and rendering lightning using adaptive grids.

**[Efficient Rendering of Lightning Taking into Account Scattering Effects due to
Clouds and Atmospheric Particles](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=883441)** propose an efficient method for creating realistic image of scenes including lightning.